# Python wrapper cannot get class property on responce object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a simple wrapper and get `w.headers` using this syntax:

```
w = wrapper
w.get_endpoints('Users')
w.headers
```

**But I get the error, headers not defined**

However this works (but not the syntax I'm after):

```
w = wrapper
w.get_endpoints('Users').headers
```

This is my code, whats wrong?

**__init__.py**

```
from .api import get_endpoints
```

**api.py**

```
def request_decorator():

    r = SessionRequest().request()
    return r

def get_endpoints():
    return request_decorator()
```

SessionRequest

```
class SessionRequest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = "This is a header"

    def request(self):

        responce = Responce()
        return responce

    def get_discovery_endpoints(self):
        pass
```

**responce**

```
class Responce(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = "test"
```

I should be getting the header "test" as Responce object is what I return, but its not available in the first example.

Comment: your `request_decorator` function is not really decorating anything- its just returning the request object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code:

```
w = wrapper
w.get_endpoints('Users')
w.headers
```

It looks like `w` is still referencing `wrapper`

If you want this behaviour:

```
w = wrapper
w.get_endpoints('Users').headers
```

You probably need this:

```
w = wrapper
e = w.get_endpoints('Users')
e.headers
```

Comment: anyway to get wrapper `w` to return `w.get_endpoints('Users')`

Comment: You haven't specified what `wrapper` is.

Comment: or just add `w.headers = e.headers`.

Answer (score 1):

If `w.get_endpoints('Users').headers` yields the result you're after, then let me explain, why

```
w.get_endpoints('Users')
w.headers
```

gives you an error:

You will need to assign the result of `w.get_endpoints('Users')` to a variable. This can be also `w`, but note that it will be overriden!

```
w = w.get_endpoints('Users')
w.headers
```

to make it more clear, you could use:

```
endpoints = w.get_endpoints('Users')
endpoints.headers
```